# Error compiling ethzasl_ptam

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy. When I run catkin_make, I receive the following error:

```
<my path>/ratio_layouted_frame.h:36:18: fatal error: QFrame: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

When I look up QFrame, it appears this is a part of pyqt4. Searching for pyqt4, I conclude this is used in the Indigo distribution. Am I correct with this assumption? Is there a way around this error?

Thanks for any help.

OK, I found something which indicates QFrame should be included with Groovy. Still can't get past this error...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210011/error-compiling-ethzasl_ptam/) by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend retrying with Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04, since that's been the current release for the last year and will have the most support. I recently compiled ethzasl_ptam on a full-desktop Indigo install by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-libg2o ros-indigo-cv-bridge liblapack-dev libblas-dev freeglut3-dev libqglviewer-dev libsuitesparse-dev libx11-dev ros-indigo-usb-cam
mkdir ~/git/myproject ~/git/myproject/src
cd ~/git/myproject/src
catkin_init_workspace
git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam.git ethzasl_ptam
cd ..
catkin_make
```

and it compiled without error.

If you're really intend on using Groovy, I suggest making sure you have necessary package for whatever provides that header file. It looks like it's probably something in RQT so you could try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rqt*
```

and then re-running the above steps.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
I've tried upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, but I receive an error message, "Unable to calculate upgrade". So, I'm stuck using Groovy and 12.04.
I tried reinstalling rqt, but I get the same error messages....

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-29**:
You likely have some non-standard packages that Ubuntu's upgrade script can't handle. I ran into a similar error. I recommend uninstalling all existing ros-groovy packages and then disabling all non-standard repos in your /etc/apt/sources.list. Once the upgrade is complete, then re-add the ROS repo.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
Uninstalling ros seems to have cleared up whatever issues were preventing me from installing 14.04, so I'm upgrading now.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
So I install 14.04, it had some issues with the graphics card. I was getting strange errors and none of the icons would show up on the desktop. I sort of fixed these issues; I can get the the terminal with ctrl+alt+f3 and operate from there. Though I still can't operate from the desktop.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
I installed Indigo, but when I run catkin_make I get a message saying it doesn't exist. When I try to reinstall catkin I get a message saying it is already the newest version.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-29**:
Running `dpkg -S /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make` shows the package is ros-indigo-catkin. If that's installed, it should be there. I can't imagine why it wouldn't be. Try reinstalling it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin`.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-29**:
Also, what brand of graphics card do you have? I had similar issues with Nvidia that I was able to sort out, but it took a lot of trial and error. Do you get to the login screen, or does even that not load?

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
I can try the catkin reinstall next time I'm at work. Today has been such a headache I may not go in tomorrow.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-05-29**:
I have an Nvidia graphics card, and I get the login screen. When I login I receive an error message saying something went wrong and I should report the error. After clicking, or not, I can move the mouse but there are no icons and keyboard commands and mouse clicks do nothing.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-01**:
I ran `dpkg -S /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make`, and it ouput `ros-indigo-catkin: /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make`. So I reinstalled and ran catkin make. It responds `catkin_make: command not found`

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-06-01**:
What does `which catkin_make` report? If it's there, then but can't be run than that means your Bash profile or Path is screwed up, which is a separate problem. If it's not there, than the package is not actually installed.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-01**:
OK, I just got catkin_make to work, but I get the message `Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed` And since I can't use the regular terminal, I can't scroll up to see other errors.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-06-01**:
What do you mean you can't use "a regular terminal"? What was the problem with catkin_make? It sounds like you have a corrupted Linux install. You need to figure that out before you tackle any ROS stuff.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-01**:
By "regular terminal" I mean the terminal that appears with ctrl+alt+t. I have to use ctrl+alt+f3. It's a graphics card driver issue I believe. The catkin issue was solved by `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` I didn't think I needed to do this, since it's included in .bashrc

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-03**:
So, I've abandoned my desktop and am now using a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and ROS Indigo. I am getting the following errors when running catkin_make
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut, -lblas, -llapack, collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-03**:
I installed the missing libraries, and catkin_make works now. I am now having a problem with launching ptam. I receive the following message: `Error: cannot launch node of type [ptam/ptam]: can't locate node [ptam] in package [ptam]`